# docker - write pipe: bad file descriptor

Tags: linux, shell, nginx, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed docker.io in ubuntu. When I am trying to build any docker container I am ending with an error **write pipe: bad file descriptor**

These are the commands I executed

`docker run nginx`

```
docker run hello-world
```

**docker version**

[image]

**docker info**
[image]

**docker images**[image: strong text]

Any ideas to solve this issue ?

Comment: add `docker version` `docker info` and `docker images`

Comment: @user2915097 I have updated my question.

Comment: Can you update your question to show those commands (`docker run nginx` and `docker run hello-world`) alongside the error that you are running into?

Comment: @programmerq both the command gives me the same error message  **write pipe: bad file descriptor**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(SOLVED : wrong arch)

Same problem on :

## uname -a

Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-43-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 12 13:45:41 UTC 2016 ppc64le ppc64le ppc64le GNU/Linux

## docker version

Client:
Version:      1.12.1
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.2
Git commit:   23cf638
Built:        Tue, 27 Sep 2016 12:25:38 +1300
OS/Arch:      linux/ppc64le

Server:
Version:      1.12.1
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.2
Git commit:   23cf638
Built:        Tue, 27 Sep 2016 12:25:38 +1300
OS/Arch:      linux/ppc64le

## docker run  hello-world

write pipe: bad file descriptor

Comment: Have you got any solution for the issue ?

Comment: maybe is something to do with this kernel message : ubuntu systemd-udevd[4203]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth720d0d3: No such file or directory  .......... every time i run the app

Comment: Ok my fault : i  have to run for my ppc64el arch . : docker run ppc64le/hello-world   ... works..

Answer (score 1):

commenting here a little more conspicuously to help future generations.  I'm running docker on 386 machine.  I was having the exact same issue, but what solved it was putting the architecture/OS before the image name; e.g.,

```
docker run i386/hello-world
```

was also able to run `sudo docker run -it i386/ubuntu bash` as expected.

EDIT: I also had to follow the instruction to [create a docker group](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group)